# Run getpts() on two figures at the same time

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to select corresponding points in 2 images in Matlab, to do this when I try to use `getpts()` first I have to select all of my points on the first image and then do this to the second image,but I want to select first point on the first image and then go to second image and select first point of that image and go back to first image and... until Nth point. is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate through a loop the number of points you want to select, e.g. `npoints=5`. You can call `getpts` for each axis, this is why I created a figure with two subplots for the demo. `getpts` does not return until you select a "final point" ("A shift-, right-, or double-click adds a final point and ends the selection."). So you have to select a final point in each loop iteration to jump to your second image. You may want to add markers at those positions you just clicked as they get lost when leaving the current `getpts` function call.

```
figure;
ax1 = subplot(121);
imshow('moon.tif');
hold on;
ax2 = subplot(122);
imshow('mandi.tif');
hold on;

npoints = 5;

for idx = 1:npoints
    fprintf('Select point %d\n', idx);

    [X1,Y1] = getpts(ax1)
    plot(X1, Y1, 'c+'); % addd marker in ax1, cyan plus sign

    [X2,Y2] = getpts(ax2)
    plot(X2, Y2, 'c+'); % addd marker in ax1, cyan plus sign
end
```